# MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT with ORDER BY strange sorting results

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my working query, no errors, but the sorting by certain columns is strange.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ServiceType, Location, Destination, Name, PAX,
                      TransferTime, Ticket SUM(PAX) AS TotalPAX,
                      GROUP_CONCAT( Coupon SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS PasTicket,
                      GROUP_CONCAT( TransferTime SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS PasTransferTime,
                      GROUP_CONCAT( Location SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS PasLocation,
                      GROUP_CONCAT( Destination SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS PasDestination,
                      GROUP_CONCAT( Name SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS PasName,
                      GROUP_CONCAT( PAX SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS PasPAX
                      FROM Reservations WHERE Date = '$DateToday'
                      GROUP BY Ticket
                      ORDER BY ServiceType, TransferTime ASC");
```

This gives me the following results which are the correct data but in wrong order:

```
REF | SERVICE   | TIME     | PAX | HOTEL      | FROM    | NAME            | TICKET
----+-----------+----------+-----+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------
17  | DEPARTURE | 15:00:00 | 1.0 | IBEROSTAR  | AIRPORT | FRANCIS EUGEN   | TICKET: #110588
18  | DEPARTURE | 15:20:00 | 2.0 | PARADISUS  | AIRPORT | MARTIN CIBBAR   | TICKET: #110589
19  | DEPARTURE | 16:40:00 | 2.0 | PARADISUS  | AIRPORT | JOHN CIA        | TICKET: #3376
20  | DEPARTURE | 16:00:00 | 2.0 | RIU PALACE | AIRPORT | ALAN KRAMER     | TICKET: #110589
21  | DEPARTURE | 16:10:00 | 2.0 | RIU PALACE | AIRPORT | JOHN WILLS      | TICKET: #110589
22  | DEPARTURE | 16:20:00 | 2.0 | RIU PALACE | AIRPORT | PETER LONG      | TICKET: #110589
```

When I `GROUP BY Ticket` the query works but the Times are out of order, however if I add `ORDER BY Time ASC` the ORDER BY does not work - `GROUP BY Time` does work but then I lose the `GROUP BY Ticket` but  I cannot use `GROUP BY Time` anyways... Number 18, 20, 21 and 22 should be GROUPED together with Time in ORDER ASC.

The ideal would be something like: `WHERE Date = '$DateToday' GROUP BY Ticket, TransferTime (LIKE '%TransferTime%') ORDER BY ServiceType, TransferTime ASC`. This is because TransferTimes can differ by some minutes and GROUP BY is too strict.

Below is an example of what it should be, GROUPED BY Ticket Number and sorted by TIME ASC. I have left the REF numbers as they were to make it clearer. Strange thing is, we have this working live but in MSSQL but the system is from 2013 and we need to pass it over to MYSQL and PHP.

```
REF | SERVICE   | TIME     | PAX | HOTEL      | FROM    | NAME            | TICKET
----+-----------+----------+-----+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------
17  | DEPARTURE | 15:00:00 | 1.0 | IBEROSTAR  | AIRPORT | FRANCIS EUGEN   | TICKET: #110588
20  | DEPARTURE | 16:00:00 | 2.0 | RIU PALACE | AIRPORT | ALAN KRAMER     | TICKET: #110589
21  | DEPARTURE | 16:10:00 | 2.0 | RIU PALACE | AIRPORT | JOHN WILLS      | TICKET: #110589
22  | DEPARTURE | 16:20:00 | 2.0 | RIU PALACE | AIRPORT | PETER LONG      | TICKET: #110589
18  | DEPARTURE | 16:40:00 | 2.0 | PARADISUS  | AIRPORT | MARTIN CIBBAR   | TICKET: #110589
19  | DEPARTURE | 16:40:00 | 2.0 | PARADISUS  | AIRPORT | JOHN CIA        | TICKET: #3376
```

GROUP_CONCAT appears to be working fine. Any ideas whats going on?

Screen dump image (names and flights changed). The data is complete and correct, but the sorting order of the ticket number is off. I realize this is because I am using GROUP BY Time which is too strict because Time can vary somewhat.

PS: The GROUP_BY SEPARATOR is a line break BR which for some reason is not being published.
[image: Screen Dump]

Comment: GROUP is not listening to ORDER BY. If you want to ORDER before GROUPING you can better use a subquery.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html

Comment: You think your data is correct but it isnt correct you are using SELECT * .... GROUP BY ticket this is misuse off the GROUP BY......Read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Right, `SELECT *` selects arbitrary values per ticket. Also I see no concatenated values in the results. The results don't seem to match the query. There should be some strings with <BR> inside.

Comment: Updated to show the table fields

Comment: I don't see what's wrong. It's 16:20 then 16:40 then 17:15. Looks correct to me.

Comment: The Tickets should be grouped, yes the Times are correct, but if you see the image the Ticket numbers are not grouped...

2OTCUN00110589
2OTCUN00110589
358229 <<<<<< This should not be there

2OTCUN00110589
2OTCUN00110589
2OTCUN00110589

Comment: A vehicle is designated to all the people with the same  Ticket number... in my example above operations would be designating 2 vehicles instead of just one. TransferTime can vary according to incoming or outgoing flights.

Answer (score 8):

**Order of GROUP_CONCAT result string**

You simply haven't stated an order for the  group_concats, which would be

```
GROUP_CONCAT(... ORDER BY ...)
```

e.g.

```
GROUP_CONCAT( Coupon ORDER BY Id SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS PasTicket
```

so the order of your group_concats is left to chance.

**Order of the rows**

As to the rows, you *have* stated an order, but you order your result by columns that are not in your select list, so this is kind of an invisible sort. (An example for clarification: if I show a list of first and last names, but behind the scenes I order these persons by the city they live in, the names will seem unordered.)

As you group by `Ticket` it is also important to know whether there is exactly one `ServiceType` and one `TransferTime` per `Ticket`. If not, you'd get the values arbitrarily picked, which is probably undesired. (Illustration: If a ticket has rows with service types A and M and Z, one of these will be picked and it is left to chance which the DBMS picks.)

**At last:**

And as has been mentioned, when you aggregate (`GROUP BY`), but `SELECT *` you will get arbitrarily picked values. Say a ticket has two rows, one with DEPARTURE | 15:00:00 and one with ARRIVAL | 18:00:00, you may even end up with DEPARTURE | 18:00:00 for the ticket.

Comment: Thanks, ermmm  Yes there is one ServiceType per ticket and ServiceType is correct throughout (GROUP BY Arrivals or Departures) , GROUP BY Ticket does work but then Times are wrong... there might be 3 entries with the same Ticket and with similar times such as 5:10, 5:14, 5:15 but not exactly the same Time. If I use GROUP BY Ticket and Time it does work but then GROUP BY Ticket gets out of order as in my example.

Comment: I have problems understanding your result. You select `*` (and I don't know what columns are in the table) plus group_concats (but I see nothing concatenated with <BR> in your results). Can you fix this? So the result matches the query? Then I may be able to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Please use ORDER BY clause inside the GROUP_CONCAT function. Here is an example query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(QUOTE(id)) ORDER BY dob ASC) as children FROM `users` WHERE id IN ("218","221","214","215").
```

It has 4 important things:

1. GROUP_CONCAT
2. DISTINCT
3. Quotes around the values
4. Adds ORDER BY clause inside the GROUP_CONCAT function